# React.js Table Sorting with Dynamic Data

Tags: reactjs, sorting, html-table, react-table

There are two different API Service Endpoints of some dynamic data like below.

```json
// from API Service A, All value are realtime changing
{
 stack : 10
 over : 2
 flow : 4
}
```

```json
// from API Service B, All value are realtime changing
{
 stack : 4
 over : 1
 flow : 2
}
```

key from two different API services are the same, but the value is different by real-time changes.

so I want to notate these differences with the table.

I coded to display this data table with *react.js* like below.

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
function App(){
 const [commonKey, setCommonKey] = useState([stack, over, flow]);
 const [dataA, setDataA] = useState({});
 const [dataB, setDataB] = useState({});

 useEffect(()=> {
  // ...periodically fetch data from API Service A and setDataA(response)
  // ...periodically fetch data from API Service B and setDataB(response)
 } ,[]);

 return (
 <>
  <table>
   <thead>
    <th>key</th>
    <th>valueA</th>
    <th>valueB</th>
    <th>A-B</th> // sorting function needed by this field value(A minus B).
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    commonKey.map((keyField)=>{
     <Mytr key={keyField} keyField={keyField} dataA={dataA[keyField]} dataB={dataB[keyField]} />
    });
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </>
)}

function Mytr({keyField, dataA, dataB}){
 return (
 <>
  <tr>
   <td>{keyField}</td>
   <td>{dataA}</td>
   <td>{dataB}</td>
   <td>{dataA - dataB}</td> // sorting function needed by this field value.
  </tr>
 </>
)}

export default App;
```

How can I add *sort by A-B value function* in this situation?

p.s Sorry for my Poor English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `sort` the `commonKey`s in the `useEffect` hook like below.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // ...periodically fetch data from API Service A and setDataA(response)
    // ...periodically fetch data from API Service B and setDataB(response)

    // get a copy of the commonKey array
    const newArr = [...commonKey];
    // sort the keys using differece of two consecutive diffs
    newArr.sort((p, q) => dataA[p] - dataB[p] - (dataA[q] - dataB[q]));
    // set the sorted array to state
    setCommonKey(newArr);
  }, []);
```

To avoid the scrolling issue, keep the `scrollY` position saved and scroll to that position once `commonKey` is updated within a [useLayoutEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect).

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const updatePosition = () => {
      setCurrentScrollY(window.scrollY);
    };
    window.addEventListener("scroll", updatePosition);
    updatePosition();
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", updatePosition);
  }, []);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, currentScrollY);
  }, [commonKey]);
```

[image: Edit pensive-mountain-blgb4]

Comment: @reaver lover, Let me know if you still have issues

Comment: Thx, Sorting is work well though, scrolling to top window on every re-rendering after sorting

Comment: can you update the sandbox to recreate the scrolling issue?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-sea-08w9k auto Scrolling to Top on every sorting occur. btw, Sorry for dirty codes.

Comment: @reaverlover, updated the answer and code sandbox ! can you please mark this as the answer once you check it?

Comment: thx a lot, but why scrolling issue is happened? seems caused by re-rendering

Comment: yeah due to rerendering. when useEffect changes the list, which trigger the rerender and useLayoutEffect runs after DOM mutations for the list and before list is painted to the DOM and preserves the scroll position.